# build path entries are missing

Tags: java, eclipse

I have copied my project from one system to another,now I am trying to run it,I am having a message in build path that 95 build path entries are missing. I am having main problem with importing some packages like:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRField


import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;


import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

import org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeDimension;


import org.krysalis.barcode4j.HumanReadablePlacement;

import org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.AbstractBarcodeBean;

import org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.code128.Code128Bean;

import org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.upcean.EAN13Bean;

import org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.java2d.Java2DCanvasProvider;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPane;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPaneContainer;

import orgimp.pushingpixels.substance.api.SubstanceLookAndFeel;

import org.pushingpixels.substance.api.SubstanceSkin;
```

Comment: Please add the required jar files to the build path.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using eclipse ,then right click on project

```
Properties->java build path
now check source all class file src is added or not,
check libraries that all necessary jar is added or not

if yor are running through comand prompt then you need to set path in command line
```

Comment: i have tried this way, all class files are added but in jar every jar is appearing with a cross symbol.and my project is not appearing in project folder of build path.

Comment: delete all jar files which red cross sign and add them again in your bulid path

Comment: in libraries what ever jar is appearing with cross symbol check the path of jar file might be  respt. jar is not present in respective path

Answer (score 0):

right click on project

go to `properties-->java build path--->Libraries`

add all library that needs in your project

and also check your java compiler

go to `properties-->java compiler`

choose necessary java compiler

------------------------------- OR ---------------------------------------------

it may be possible that required jar files are not present in your lib folder

Comment: yes i checked it my lib folder is empty.now how to resolve this problem?

Comment: add your all jar into lib folder that are necessary for your project and then add it into your class path

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting those entries from build path (make sure you leave the jars which eclipse already can find).

Comment: It may be a good idea if you can explain what you are saying in detail. That will help many SO users.